# Image Path Ionic 2

Tags: ionic, path, image, img

Sou novo no Ionic, venho de desenvolvimento nativo com android e estou um pouco perdido em relação ao apontamento das imagens no IONIC.

Estou criando na page inicial, que chamo de HOME, um menu com quatro opções onde o background de cada opção serão imagens.

Desta forma, coloco o caminho relativo (onde as imagens estão dentro da pasta /src/assets) e rodo o comando $ ionic serve, e funciona normalmente no browser. Contudo, quando faço $ ionic run android, as imagens não aparecem no meu smartphone ou emulador.

Imagino que isso deve ser uma tremenda besteira, mas pra quem ta começando é trabalhoso. Já fazem umas 24 horas que pesquiso, leio conteúdo e não consigo resolver meu problema.

Qual o local correto para colocar as imagens? Como devo referenciar o caminho?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 4):

Encontrei!!!

link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952214/correct-way-to-use-image-assets-in-ionic-2

Traduzindo:

Se colocar as imagens dentro de www/img, funcionarão apenas localmente através do $ ionic serve. Pra resolver o problema usando esta forma, é necessário usar o gulp para copiar as imagens para a pasta que você quer antes do build.

Contudo, a forma anterior está obsoleta. O recomendado é usar as imagens dentro de assets/images e referencia-las com src="assets/images/sua-imagem.extensão" Desta forma funcionará tanto localmente quanto em emuladores e devices.